# using theorem about sequences to prove property of subset of a subspace of a metric space

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to work through Gamelin and Greene and am stuck on chapter 1 question 9.

Let Y be a subspace of X and let S be a subset of Y.  Show that the closure of S in Y = $\bar{S} \cap Y$ where $\bar{S}$ is the closure of S in X.

The hint in the book suggests to use the following theorem: If Y is a subset of a metric space X, $x \in X$ is adherent to Y iff there exists a sequence in Y with limit x.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll write $\bar{S}_{Y}$ for the closure of $S$ in $Y$. Note that $\bar{S}_{Y}\subset Y$. If $y\in\bar{S}_{Y}$, then there is a sequence in $S$ converging to $y$ in $Y$. Since $Y$ is a subspace of $X$, the sequence also converges to $y$ in $X$. This shows that $y\in\bar{S}$. Thus $\bar{S}_{Y}\subseteq\bar{S}\cap Y$.

The converse is pretty much the same.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking I needed to construct some clever sequence but that clears things up for me. Sorry I don't have enough reputation to upvote you.